# trying to make a fixed text box that creates another when its text limit is reached. pyqt5

Tags: python, windows, pyqt5

I'm new to this coding thing and I'm trying to make a word processor using pyqt5. I'm stuck trying to make a QTextBox and/or a QPlainTextBox that creates another text box when the one above it is full with text, exactly how in a google docs when you reach the end of the page another is automatically created and the you can just keep typing. the problem is that a word limit doesn't acount for images, empty lines, etc.

in all honesty, i will settle for a text box that Isn't infinite, aka when you reach the end of the text box that's it, you cant type in any more words as the limit has been reached, though you can still go back and edit the text, and then manually add a page via a menu or something. there is surprisingly little documentation on how to do this, and i myself have been attempting to find a solution for two or so days, to the point were my code has become eldritch to me, and i don't think it will be of any help, either way, here is what i got.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
-------------
(other stuff)
-------------
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)

        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        # Create a scroll area
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.scrollArea.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 30, 400, 400))
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(False)
        self.scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.scrollArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

        # Create a QTextEdit widget
        self.a4page = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.a4page.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 400, 400))

        self.a4page.setFixedSize(400, 400)  # Set fixed size for the QTextEdit
        # Calculate the maximum number of lines based on the fixed size
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)  # Adjust the font size as needed
        self.a4page.setFont(font)
        max_lines = self.a4page.height() // QtGui.QFontMetrics(font).lineSpacing()

        self.a4page.setMaximumBlockCount(max_lines)

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

Comment: I understand the need for what you want, but using multiple text editors to achieve this is not only inappropriate, but also wrong. For instance, setting the maximum block count is invalid, as it doesn't consider word wrapping (a *block* can contain multiple lines if they are too long and you want to limit the horizontal size the page width); the same goes for trying to set the maximum character count, and for the opposite reason (you would easily reach the bottom of the page with lines that only have a single characters, while still having lots of available characters for the content). »

Comment: » Another important problem would be dealing with selections and clipboard management: you wouldn't be able to easily paste text that goes beyond the maximum line count (unless you carefully implement it by hand), nor create a selection that begins in one "page" and ends in another. You have to consider that the systems behind text layout engines are quite complex, and the Qt text editors have not been implemented to support pagination display. It *is* doable, but you have to completely implement the text document layout on your own, which requires sufficient knowledge and experience with »

Comment: » the whole QTextDocument API, something that is complex to achieve, and even more difficult considering your current experience; for instance: you are using a QPlainTextEdit, while you mention QTextEdit in your comments, but those two widgets, while similar and using a common API, are in fact unrelated; you are also editing a pyuic generated file, which is considered bad practice and is highly discouraged (as the warning in the comments on top of those files clearly says; follow the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)).

Comment: @musicamante
damn, i was really hoping the answer would be something simple that i missed, but it looks like its the opposite of that. thanks for the answer by the way, i will ignore the text box problem and just focus on the rest of the word processor, at the same time i will keep searching for a solution on the side, there are still pyqt5 api's, add ones, and what nots to look at. thanks agains!

Comment: I can assure you that the only solution is what I wrote above (completely write the layout engine). The "PyQt5 API" **are** the Qt API: PyQt is just the python binding around the Qt library, it doesn't add absolutely anything more. I have some fair amount of experience with the QTextDocument framework, including studying the C++ sources of most of its related classes: there are no shortcuts or hidden ways to easily do that; it's how these editors were intended since the beginning, and while supporting these aspects *is* possible, they didn't add it by default, and for good reasons.

Comment: There may be a *half-way* solution. You could [set the page-size of the document](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#pageSize-prop) and then use the [auto-page-break policy](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextformat.html#PageBreakFlag-enum) when formatting the text. Something like that should at least allow you to *display* the current pagination in a separate [print-preview widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprintpreviewwidget.html). So, not a fully integrated WYSIWYG interface, but still *functionally* equivalent to some extent. (NB: this is all air-code - I haven't actually tried any of it).

Comment: on my search i found something called QScintilla, a port of Scintilla to python that is supposed to be a robust text editor which can work seamlessly with pyqt5 and 6. i have attempted to use it to find a solution, but there is a surprising lack of documentation. i will keep looking but at the same time will ask if anyone has been able to make a google doc type text editor using QScintilla.